# Wamp SSL configuration throws 404

Tags: windows, ssl, apache-2.4

I have a domain which is mapped to an ip address.

http://test.main.com works FINE. https://test.main.com DOES NOT works, getting 404 error.

Please help me to find out the problem

**Below is my httpd-ssl.con file**

```
 <VirtualHost *:443>
    DocumentRoot "D:/ews/liveenergy/myapp"
    ServerName test.main.com:443
    ServerAdmin admin@localhost
    ErrorLog "C:/wamp32/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.4.9/logs/apache_error.log"
    TransferLog "C:/wamp32/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.4.9/logs/access.log"
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT56:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW:+SSLv2:+EXP:+eNULL

    SSLCertificateFile "C:/wamp32/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.4.9/conf/ssl.crt/ServerCertificate.crt"        

    SSLCertificateKeyFile "C:/wamp32/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.4.9/conf/ssl.key/rms_bldgot_com.key"        

    SSLCertificateChainFile "C:/wamp32/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.4.9/conf/ssl.crt/ChainBundle1.crt"
    <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </FilesMatch>

    <Directory "D:/ews/liveenergy/myapp">
    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All

    Order Deny,Allow
    Allow from 127.0.0.1
    </Directory>
    BrowserMatch ".*MSIE.*" \
    nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
    downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0

    CustomLog "C:/wamp/logs/ssl_request.log" \
    "%t %h %{SSL_PROTOCOL}x %{SSL_CIPHER}x \"%r\" %b"
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Compare it to the other virtual host, which you didn't post (and should have done).

Comment: @MichaelHampton i have only one virtual host configuration done in httpd-ssl.conf

Comment: Then how is it that "http://test.main.com works FINE" if you have no configuration for it?